# Does the concatenation of two text files, which compile under tex, always compile under tex?

Tags: plain-tex

In other words, does the set of all text files that compile under tex form a monoid under concatenation?

I have recently dabbled a bit in plain tex and my algebraic spider senses were immediately tingling. I thought I'd google the answer with ease, but so far I have found nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a plain tex file ends by `\bye` (and a latex file ends by `\end{document}`), and everything after this is ignored.  So your statement is trivially correct, since the second file is ignored after concatenation.

If we consider `\bye` to be a "metacommand", dropped in a concatenation, then your statement is incorrect.

Consider the files

```
\def\aa{0}
\aa
\bye
```

and

```
\def\bb{0}
\bb
\ifx\aa\bb\cc\fi
\bye
```

Each of them compiles, but the concatenation does not:

```
\def\aa{0}
\aa
\def\bb{0}
\bb
\ifx\aa\bb\cc\fi
\bye
```

produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \ifx\aa\bb\cc
                 \fi
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

The reason is, undefined `\aa` is undefined in the second file, but is the same as `\bb` in the concatenated one.

Comment: Only a nitpicking remark: in the second file `\aa` is not `\relax`, it's simply undefined, as far as `\ifx` is concerned. The test `\ifx\UnDeFiNeD\relax` returns false, if `\UnDeFiNeD` is undefined.

Comment: I stand corrected.  PS.  It was great to see you in Darmstadt!

Answer (score 4):

In plain TeX a properly formatted file will end in `\bye` to tell the compiler to stop looking for input.  Therefore the concatenation will only compile the first file then the rest is ignored.. (So no.)  In LaTeX, a compilable file will end in `\end{document}` again to tell the compiler it is done. So only the first file in the concatenation will compile and the rest is ignored.  Plus the second file will have a preamble now in an location which would cast a compiling error if i was seen. (So no.)

Not discussed are additional impacts of packages, fonts, inputted file, etc.